# Get the Total value of sum of 2 columns in db laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I have joined 2 databases, what i want is to get the total value/sum of these 2 multiplied column:

Example on the database:

Price      Quantity
100          1
110          2
120          3

in my query in laravel- i got the total, 100, 220, 360, i want the sum of all these, total that is equals to, 680, how can i achieve the 680 total?

```
    $jointwo = DB::table('invoices')
                ->select('invoices.id', 'invoices.user', 'invoices.company', 'invoices.invoice_month', 'invoices.created','invoice_details.invoice_id', DB::raw('invoice_details.quantity * invoice_details.unit_price as total'))->join('invoice_details', 'invoice_details.invoice_id', '=', 'invoices.id')->get();


     dd($jointwo);
```

I got the total, 100, 220, 360, i want the sum of all these, total that is equals to, 680, how can i achieve the 680 total?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, group by *invoices.id* `->groupBy('invoices.id')` and then get the total amount.

```php
$jointwo = DB::table('invoices')
    ->select('invoices.id', 'invoices.user', 'invoices.company', 'invoices.invoice_month', 'invoices.created')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(invoice_details.quantity * invoice_details.unit_price) as total')
    ->join('invoice_details', 'invoice_details.invoice_id', '=', 'invoices.id')
    ->groupBy('invoices.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: thankssssssss. you saved my day with this code